# My Discord bot wont show the embed and has no errors what do i do?

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

When I code the embed, it doesn't work

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'it shows the servers ping',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00A6FF')
        .setTitle('Ping')
        .setURL('https://discord.gg/X9cpCJ8F5J')
        .setDescription('Test')
        .setFooter('Test');
        
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

No errors, doesn't send the embed doesn't even send a message, no message and no errors

Comment: What about command code, like where you make the bot listen for the command? Can you post that? If there are no errors, it’s possible your code isn’t even running

Answer (score 0):

**If you use discord.js:**

You can use this code instead (official manual of discord.js):

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

**If you use discord.py:**

You can use this code instead (I tested with my bot also):

```py
  if message.content.startswith("!command"):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="ping", description="Test", color=0x00A6FF)
        embed.set_author(name="Test", url="https://discord.gg/X9cpCJ8F5J", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/541913766296813570/672624076589760512/DRG.png")
        embed.set_footer(text="Test")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```